# Google's Fusion Tables Layer: IN query - what about multiple columns?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want a google map where I can query different columns from my fusion table to display on the map when a user selects a checkbox. Google's Fusion Tables Layer Example: IN query is great if the data you want to display is in one column, but mine is in multiple columns, and I am not a programmer and cannot figure this out.

Is it possible to query different columns to display on your map using checkboxes?

Lets use the IN query example from above.
Here is the map and code: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/in
Here is the fusion table: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw

Lets say there are additional columns to the fusion table: A, B, and C with a "yes" or "no" value like the delivery column.
I want the map to load with all stores displayed, and
I want checkboxes for:
delivery
A
B
C
So the user can select/deselect these using the checkbox and then those with "yes" will display on the map.

Is this even possible? If so, could someone please provide the code? I have looked everywhere and cannot find an example like this that pulls from different columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Derek Eder's [Searchable Map Template](http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/), which lets you build a filtered map such as you are describing.

Comment: The Searchable Map Template seems to only deal with displaying data from one column. How do I use checkboxes for multiple columns?